# Handling a child entity insertion in an API REST with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a parent/child entity which is defined as follows:

In **Employee** class:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
```

In **Phone** class:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Employee employee;
```

And when I want to insert or get a new phone in the resource `/employees/{employeeId}/phones/{id}` inside `PhoneService`

```
    @Override // POST
    public Phone createPhone(long employeeId, @Valid Phone phone) {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId).orElseThrow(() -> 
            new EntityNotFoundException("Could not find an employee for the provided ID.")    
        );

//      ## option 1
        employee.addPhone(phone);
        phone.setEmployee(employee);

        employeeRepository.save(employee);

        return phoneRepository.findById(phone.getId()).orElseThrow(() ->
            new EntityNotFoundException("Could not find a phone for the provided ID.")
        );

//      ## option 2
//      phone.setEmployee(employee);
//      return phoneRepository.save(phone);
    }

    @Override // GET
    public Phone getPhone(long employeeId, long id) {
        return phoneRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() ->
            new EntityNotFoundException("Could not find a phone for the provided ID.")
        );
    }
```

I feel option 2 is easier but I am technically doing it wrong because I am straight out looking for the phone in the DB without caring about its employee's ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think Option2 is correct. The only thing you missed is adding a unique key on (PhoneNumber + Ic) because logically one (phoneNumber + ic) should be only related to one Employee.

About Option1, the API is called "createPhone", but it's actually operating on the Employee Table, which I think is misleading and wrong.

The more appropriate code should be like:

```java
public Phone createPhone(Long employeeId, Phone phone) {
   phone.setEmployeeId(employeeId);
   return phoneRepository.save(phone);
}

//Ohter API about update an employee with the whole phone list
public Phone updateEmployee(Long employeeId, List<Phone> phones) {
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId).orElseThrow(() -> 
            new EntityNotFoundException("Could not find an employee for the provided ID.")    
        );
    employee.setPhone(phones);
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "ic"? Also I believe the method `createPhone` you posted won't work since I can't save a relationship like that, I need to fetch the employee.

Comment: IC is a country code, ic+phoneNumber should be unique all over the world. Since this is the OneToMany relationship, you don't need to change the Employee table when you insert phones, because you only need an `employeeId` field in the Phone table to keep the OneToMany relationship. If you want to search Employee with phones, the sql should be 
SELECT e.*, p.phone FROM employee e JOIN phone p ON e.id=p.employeeId where e.id=?"